# GKE: setting nodeCount to zero using setSize API does not set number of nodes per zone to zero

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm following the python example from the [**`setSize`**](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.clusters.nodePools/setSize) API and I'm setting the `nodeCount` to zero to remove all the nodes on my cluster (and also disabling auto-scaling) like this:

```py
    gke = discovery.build("container", "v1", credentials=credentials)
    set_node_pool_size_request_body = {"nodeCount": 0}
    set_node_pool_autoscaling_request_body = {"autoscaling": {"enabled": False}}

    gke.projects()
    .locations()
    .clusters()
    .nodePools()
    .setSize(name=name, body=set_node_pool_size_request_body).execute()

    gke.projects()
    .locations()
    .clusters()
    .nodePools()
    .setAutoscaling(name=name, body=set_node_pool_autoscaling_request_body).execute()
```

I was expecting it to set the number of nodes per zone to zero on my node pool (note: image below is manually set):
[image]

Setting it manually works. All my nodes are gone and none of the pods get scheduled. When doing it via API though, it just sets it to blank which seems to cause one node to be left out, causing some of my pods to get scheduled which I don't want:

[image]

Is `nodeCount` the correct field to set the number of nodes per zone? I'm fairly new to GKE and kubernetes in general so I apologise if this is a very basic question. Also tried looking around for questions but haven't found anything close.

I do know GKE needs at least one node to run system pods, but in this case I need all of them gone which should be fine because I'm managing my cluster using GCP?

**EDIT**:
Before running the script, I set the node count per zone to 1 and I enabled the auto-scaler. After running the script, the node count per zone is blank (as from the image above) and the auto-scaler gets disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For others who face the same issue, apparently it just needs a timeout in between the commands, since operations are still being executed on the cluster. It seems 5 minutes was needed in this case, so:

```py
import time

# ...

gke.projects()
.locations()
.clusters()
.nodePools()
.setSize(name=name, body=set_node_pool_size_request_body).execute()

# Wait 5 minutes before disabling the auto-scaler
time.sleep(300)

gke.projects()
.locations()
.clusters()
.nodePools()
.setAutoscaling(name=name, body=set_node_pool_autoscaling_request_body).execute()
```